# What are the persistent storage options for Windows Docker on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, azure-storage

When using (Linux) Docker on Azure, there is the Azure volume driver to mount blob storage. However this is Linux only.

Is there an offical way to mount persistent (blob based) storage against Azure Windows containers?

Comment: I recall reading that they were working on a driver. If I could only find the reference again...